# Mapping volume from one container into another one

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, pytest

I'm learning docker and jenkins, and what I'm trying to do is to get tests result from docker container which I'm running tests on, to docker container on which I have running jenkins. So, I have docker container with jenkins:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

WORKDIR /app

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y python3 && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    apt-get install -y python3-venv && \
    curl https://get.docker.com/ > dockerinstall && chmod 777 dockerinstall && ./dockerinstall
```

I'm running it through powershell script that I wrote:

```
$USER = Read-Host -Prompt "Provide username: "
$PASSWORD = Read-Host -Prompt "Provide password: "

docker login --username $USER --password $PASSWORD
docker build -t test/jenkins_with_python:1 .
docker push test/jenkins_with_python:1
docker rmi test/jenkins_with_python:1

docker pull test/jenkins_with_python:1
docker run --rm --privileged -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v C:directory\JenkinsOutput/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock test/jenkins_with_python:1

# usr: admin pass: 4b087d3494a54d25a2734e74e387b8b1
```

And I have Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Running unit tests") {
            steps {
                sh "docker login --username <username> --password <password"
                sh "docker pull test/calculator_pytests:1"
                sh "docker run --rm --privileged -v /app/result.json:/app/result.json test/calculator_pytests:1"                
                sh "docker cp test/calculator_pytest:1:/app/result.json /app/result.json"
            }

            post {
                always {
                    junit testResults: '**/*result.xml'
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Running calculator app") {
            steps {
                sh "python3 ./calculator/calculator.py"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile which is pulled from docker hub via Jenkinsfile is looking like that:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \    
    python3 -m venv venv && \
    . venv/bin/activate && \
    pip3 install -r "requirements.txt"

COPY . .

RUN rm "requirements.txt"

CMD ["sh", "-c", ". venv/bin/activate && pytest -v --junit-xml=result.xml"]
```

As a result, I know that result.xml file is created on docker container with pytest, but I cannot somehow get it on a container with jenkins. I tried a lot of combinations, but with my current understanding I really don't know why posted code is not working. I would assume that from these two line:

```
sh "docker run --rm --privileged -v /app/result.json:/app/result.json test/calculator_pytests:1"                
sh "docker cp test/calculator_pytest:1:/app/result.json
```

actually only the first one would be enough. But of course it isn't. I really cannot think of any solution to it. Can someone give me some idea?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Jenkins but, one (!) mechanism for sharing files between containers (which you're using for `calculator_pytests:1` is to mount folders|files on the host system into the containers that need to share the data. This can cause sync issues when the containers attempt to access the files concurrently but, in your case, the containers appear sequential and so there should be no problem.

Comment: Run `calculator_pytests:1` as you are mounting `host:container` (`/app/result.json:/app/result.json`) and then mount the files into Jenkins and ensure Jenkins references them as mounted e.g. `/app/result.json:/path/to/result.json` would mount the host machine's `/app/result/json` as  `/pathto/result.json` in the Jenkins container.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure If I understand you, can you share what is the issue with more details?